# Add関数を使用して作成したボタン押下時の処理内容を定義するには？

Tags: vba, ms-word, ms-office

WordのVBAにおける以下の関数を用いて動的に生成したCommandButtonのClickイベントの処理はどのようにすれば定義できるのでしょうか？
https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/add-method-microsoft-forms

CommandButtonは同名のクラスがいくつかあるようですが、今回はWordのUserFormにおけるCommandButtonを生成するとのことです。
https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/commandbutton-control

同名のこのCommandButton(Access)と同じようにOnClickプロパティを指定しようとしてもOnClickプロパティ自体がない様子のため失敗しました。
https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/vba/api/access.commandbutton